# How to run a Word macro from Python?

Tags: python, vba, ms-word, pywin32, comtypes

I am trying this code, but I am getting the following error: `Can´t run the specified macro`.

```
import os
import comtypes.client

path = r"path to the .docm file where I saved the vba macro"

word=comtypes.client.CreateObject("Word.Application")
word.Documents.Open(path,ReadOnly=1)
word.Run("Complete.Macro.Name")
word.Documents(1).Close(SaveChanges=0)
word.Application.Quit()
wd=0
```

In addition I would like to save the new document after the macro, not sure if the code is correct to do so.

Also, tried using win32 , but got the same result

```
import win32com.client as win32

word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = True

doc = word.Documents.Open(r'path to file .docx')
   
word.Application.Run("Complete.Macro.Name")
```

Comment: Are macros enabled in Word? Did you have a chance to check the Trust Center settings?

Comment: Where is your macro stored? Is it a document?

Comment: It is a docx document.

Comment: You may try to specify the document in the `Run` method call parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I tried opening the file from the python folder using a file name variable instead of specifying a path. it works fine for me . I think the problem is with the macro, may be try to create the macro from scratch again.

```
doc = word.Documents.Open(file_name)
word.Application.Run("your_macro_name")
```